# Redirecting using hash-router and the Github OAuth web flow?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm using react-router's HashRouter and as a result I think this might be causing problems for my redirect. I've had problems using BrowserRouter and so I'd like to stick with HashRouter if at all possible.

Essentially, Github's OAuth documentation requires that the root path of your redirect URI be the same path for your initial callback URI. So you can have: "/callback/validated" but not "/somethingdifferent/validated". The problem is that my callback URI is just an endpoint for my node-express server that then posts for the access token. It isn't a route on my client side. And since I'm using hash-router, saying: "/#/callback/validated" is not the same as "/callback/validated", but the former is where I would like the client to be redirected - because that's what I got working on the front end.

Unfortunately I can't list the former path as my redirect URI because it doesn't build on the callback I specified. I've tried changing the callback URI and the server endpoint to be "/#/callback" and while this redirects succesfully, it doesn't end up calling my server's endpoint and so nothing is actually authenticated.

Is there any way I can get around this without using BrowserRouter?

Comment: I ended up not using react-router, and just using express' redirect() for simplicity.